# The resource cannot be found While opening Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I've been facing this problem in the last hours, I can no longer open orchard cms,  it always prompt me an error saying

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

But Strangely I still can open my Admin Page/Dashboard.

I use a page as a Home Page, now when I view this page from the Admin area I can open the webpage successfully!  e.g http://domain:9999/homepage
but when I click on the home domain http://domain:9999/

i always get this error

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly

I hope my question is not too confusing, the summary is that I cannot Access the main root webpage  domain:9999 but still can access all it's pages  domain:9999/page

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Is the homepage checkbox still checked?

Comment: I unchecked and check it back again, publish and it's working now :) Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it working. It was just a guess though, I have no idea what might have caused the error so I can't write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but the cause was a MySQL database that could not be reached.

My web browser displayed the same error: The resource cannot be found.

If you check the logfile you may find the error: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Solution: Check the connection string. You can find it in:
~\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt